# KeyError when trying to compress image using PIL

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to compress uploaded images using PIL for quicker uploads. Here's my views:

```
print(instance.image) #prints "imagename.jpg"
instance.image = Image.open(instance.image)
print(instance.image) #prints "<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=3190x2159 at 0x10EE73A20>"
instance.image.thumbnail((220, 130), Image.ANTIALIAS)
print(instance.image) #prints "<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=193x130 at 0x10EE73A20>"
instance.image.save(instance.image, quality=60)
```

that last line sparks the error.

```
Traceback:

File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/project/site/post/views.py" in post
  55.                 instance.image.save(instance.image, quality=60)

File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/Image.py" in save
  1713.             format = EXTENSION[ext]

Exception Type: KeyError at /post/
Exception Value: ''
```

Any idea what the problem is?

EDIT: The following code:

```
...
if form_post.is_valid():
    instance = form_post.save(commit=False)
    instance.user = request.user

if instance.image:
    filename = instance.image
    instance.image = Image.open(instance.image)
    instance.image.thumbnail((220, 130), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    instance.image.save(filename, quality=60)

instance.save()
```

returns `'JpegImageFile' object has no attribute '_committed'` error on the last line (`instance.save()`)

Comment: `instance.image.save(instance.image)` is erroneous, check [`Image.save` docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.save): _fp – A filename (string), pathlib.Path object or file object._

Comment: `instance.image` is the image filename initially, but then you overwrite it in `instance.image = Image.open(instance.image)`. Save it into another variable and use the filename when saving the image.

Comment: Sweet I've got that bit working now. But I've now got a problem of (double saving?) - the `instance.image` is already saved when I perform `instance.save()` later on. I looked at the docs to see if I can perform `commit=False` when I'm saving the image but it doesn't appear to be available. Is there any way around this?

Comment: What field does `image` refer to? Show your (reduced) model class.

Comment: `image = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)`